# Why does "activator eclipse" yield "Not a valid project ID: eclipse" in a new project?

Tags: eclipse, playframework, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.4

I just created a new project using `activator new`, and am now trying to eclipsify it using `activator eclipse`. But I am facing an issue:

```
D:\work\firebase>activator eclipse
[info] Loading project definition from D:\work\firebase\project
[info] Set current project to firebase (in build file:/D:/work/firebase/)
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
[error]        ^
```

I am using Typesafe Activator 1.3.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Append this piece to your `plugins.sbt` file:

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")`

> Play no longer includes the sbteclipse or sbt-idea plugins, which enables users to upgrade IDE support independently of Play.

[Source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24)

Comment: I tried this but it is not working! I am using Windows 8.1 with Java 8 update  74, activator version 1.3.9. and play 2.5!

Comment: I'd like to add that you can use the global `plugins.sbt` in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/` or the one in the `project/` folder of your project ([Installing sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Installing-sbteclipse)).

Comment: What a crap. My first experiences with the Play 2 Framework and I'm getting errors by just doing what the docs say. That doesn't look very professional.

Comment: Don't forget to use the correct plugin version. For 2.5 I'm adding:
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
to project/plugins.sbt

Comment: @CaseyMurray Edit the answer, please. :-)

Answer (score 5):

According to James Ward:

> I think the shims only get installed by the UI. But jsuereth can confirm. If so we need to fix this. A workaround is to first run the UI (`activator ui`) on the project, then you can use `activator eclipse`

Source: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/212

Answer (score 0):

I solved by this way:

## 1 add line addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")

## 2 then run activator eclipse

Comment: this is same as accepted answer, just only in bold letter ;)